# Folland real analysis, theorem 2.40

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling with the proof of theorem 2.40 in Folland's real analysis, where he states

[image]

I think we have obtained:
$$V_j \subset U_j  \text{ for all } j$$
$$m(V) \geq m(U) - \epsilon$$
$$m(U) \leq m(E) + 2\epsilon$$
But I'm unaware of how to reach the relations circled in orange in the above proof. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty U_j$ implies $$\begin{align}
E\setminus \bigcup_1^N V_j
&\subseteq
\left(\bigcup_1^\infty U_j\right) \setminus \left(\bigcup_1^N V_j\right)
\\
&= \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \left(U_j \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k\right)\end{align}.$$.

For each $j$, we have $$\left(U_j \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k\right) \overset{(i)}{\subseteq} (U_j \setminus V_j) \overset{(ii)}{\subseteq} U_j.$$ Applying (i) for $j \le N$, and applying both (i) and (ii) for $j > N$, we have
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \left(U_j \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k\right)
\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N (U_j \setminus V_j) \cup \bigcup_{j=N+1}^\infty U_j.$$

Finally, take the measure of both sides, and apply a union bound to get the first inequality. Bounding by $2\epsilon$ simply requires citing the properties of $U_j$ and $V_j$.

---

For the second, apply a similar reasoning, using the fact that $V_j \subseteq U_j$.

---

Response to comment:

For the first term in the first inequality,
$$m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^N (U_j \setminus V_j)\right)
\le \sum_{j=1}^N (m(U_j)- m(V_j))
\le \sum_{j=1}^N \epsilon 2^{-j} < \epsilon.$$
For the second inequality you know $\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(U_j)$ is finite, so for all sufficiently large $N$ such that $\sum_{j=N+1}^\infty m(U_j) < \epsilon$.

For the second inequality,
$$m\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty U_j \setminus E\right)
= m(U) - m(E) \le 2\epsilon$$
It seems like the proof should have $\le 2\epsilon$ instead of $< \epsilon$ but this doesn't impact the conclusion of the proof.

Comment: Thanks! After getting $m(E\setminus \bigcup_1^N V_j) \leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^N (U_j \setminus V_j)) + m(\bigcup_{j=N+1}^\infty U_j)$ and $m(\bigcup_{j=1}^N (V_j \setminus E)) \leq m(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (U_j \setminus E))$, may I ask how do we bound them by $2\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$, respectively? I'm not aware of how to do it...

Comment: @sam2018 See my update.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!